# Does "Text" in the HTML5 syntax mean "any character"?

Tags: html, text, syntax

I wasn't able to find any restrictions what characters are allowed in [Text](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#syntax-text) does this imply that erverthing is allowed or are there restrictions that affect HTML documents in general?

For example the [Character Reference Section](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#character-references) states that:

> The numeric character reference forms [...] are allowed to reference any Unicode code point other than U+0000, U+000D, permanently undefined Unicode characters (noncharacters), surrogates (U+D800–U+DFFF), and control characters other than space characters.

Are those characters still allowed in their "unescaped" form in Text? E.g. as [attribute value](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#attributes-2): `<span title="Hello ␀ World"></span>` where ␀ is the U+0000 NULL character (**not** U+2400).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character restriction for text on your page and in your markup is defined according to your selected *character set*. If you don't define a character set, the browser will take a guess or assert its default option (usually, whatever is the least restrictive). The character set is defined by using the [`meta` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta) with the [`charset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#attr-charset) attribute in your document's `head` section. The most common example of this uses the [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) character set:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

The value of this attribute can be any of the character sets defined by the [Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA)](http://www.iana.org/). The full list of defined character sets is available [here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml).

Additionally, there may be specific restrictions on *unescaped* text used within certain elements (or types of elements). In this case, you would have to read the specifications for that tag or type of tag, or simply escape the characters in question by replacing them with their [ampersand-encoded html entities escape values](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref).

Comment: Thanks, does this inlude characters like U+0000 NULL? (I updates my question accordingly)

Comment: @User7623045 the backslash is used to escape characters, so in your example, `\0` is actually escaped. It looks like the document you linked to is simply saying that you are not permitted to use the ampersand technique for escaping the null value. according to everything i read, as long as the null value is in your character set, there is nothing technically preventing you for using it unescaped in your markup.

Comment: as far as i know in HTML the blackslash is not used as a character to escape other characters (thats what the entities are used for). `\0` was just used because I can't enter a real U+0000 NULL character in a question (maybe I can clearify this more by using a diffrent placeholder).

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that there is any restriction which is there on Text in  the context which you have pointed. The text here means all the allowed alphabets,numbers and alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the link you provided:

> Text is allowed inside elements, attribute values, and comments. ***Extra constraints are placed on what is and what is not allowed in text based on where the text is to be put, as described in the other sections***

Now if we go to the syntax definition for [CDATA sections](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#cdata-sections:syntax-text):

> CDATA sections must consist of the following components, in this
>   order:
>
> 1. The string "<![CDATA[".
> 2. Optionally, text, ***with the additional restriction that the text must not contain the string "]]>"***.
> 3. The string "]]>".

So every type of content has it's own set of restrictions, and text is just used to define the superset of all characters, symbols and so on...

Comment: Thanks, I was asking because I was a bit curious when I read in the section for attributes:
> Attribute values are a mixture of text and character references [..].
And the character reference section states that:
> The numeric character reference forms [..] are allowed to reference any Unicode code point other than U+0000, U+000D, permanently undefined Unicode characters (noncharacters), surrogates (U+D800–U+DFFF), and control characters other than space characters.
I thougt maybe there was a reason for that and that those characters might also be forbidden unescaped in text.